# Crash when using fragment in AndroidView using compose

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-jetpack-compose

I'm playing around with compose and tried to include a fragment inside a compose AndroidView.

So in my situation, we have AFragment with a ComposeView and inside the ComposeView there is an AndroidView which create a FragmentContainerView and add a PIFragment.

```kotlin
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        return ComposeView(requireContext()).apply {
            setContent {
                AppTheme {
                    GalleryScreen(
                        factory = viewModelFactory,
                        remoteConfig = remoteConfig,
                        id = id,
                        currentPosition = currentPositionState,
                        onBack = { router.back(requireActivity()) },
                    ) {
                        AndroidView(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .fillMaxWidth()
                                .wrapContentHeight(),
                            factory = {
                                FragmentContainerView(context).apply {
                                    id = R.id.pFIC
                                }
                            },
                            update = {
                                childFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(
                                    R.id.pFIC,
                                    PIFragment::class.java,
                                    buildArguments(
                                        id = id,
                                        origin = origin,
                                    ), null
                                ).commitAllowingStateLoss()
                            },
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

All was working fine, but when we publish this code in production, we saw crash in firebase:

```
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0b072b (...:id/pFIC) for fragment PIFragment{ef1f89b} (bdbe15f0-679d-41bb-8a27-367655f73545 id=0x7f0b072b)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:513)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:282)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:112)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1647)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3128)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchViewCreated(FragmentManager.java:3065)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:2988)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:546)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:282)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2180)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2100)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2002)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$5.run(FragmentManager.java:524)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In fact, the crash was happening after the parent fragment was recreated.

In my case because of navigation:

- AFragment (with PIFragment)
- navigate to BFragment
- back to AFragment

Crash, because the fragment manager is trying to recreate AFragment and PIFragment, but the compose pass is not done so pFIC does not exist yet.

The solution was to remove the PIFragment when the parent fragment view is destroyed.

```kotlin
    override fun onDestroyView() {
        childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.pFIC)?.let { fragment ->
            childFragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commitAllowingStateLoss()
        }
        super.onDestroyView()
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You should also be using `AndroidViewBinding` instead of `AndroidView` for adding a fragment in Compose. `AndroidViewBinding` has fragment-specific handling that will ensure that fragments are removed when the containing composable is disposed of. Note that this requires view binding to be enabled.

Define your FragmentContainerView in XML like so:

```
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/fragment_container_view"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:name="com.example.MyFragment" />
```

...and then in your composable function:

```
@Composable
fun FragmentInComposeExample() {
    AndroidViewBinding(MyFragmentLayoutBinding::inflate) {
        val myFragment = fragmentContainerView.getFragment<MyFragment>()
        // ...
    }
}
```

You can read [Fragment in Compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/interop/interop-apis#fragments-in-compose) for more info.

Comment: Is `FragmentContainerView` a separate layout file that resides next to the Fragment's original layout file?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky yes that would be a separate XML file. I've got a test branch here that demonstrates this in the Sunflower sample app which you can check out https://github.com/android/sunflower/tree/top-down-migration

Comment: This actually works and also the documented way. Has to be the accepted answer.
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/migrate/interoperability-apis/views-in-compose?authuser=1#:~:text=InteroperabilityAPIsSnippets.kt-,Fragments%20in%20Compose,-Use%20the%20AndroidViewBinding

Comment: androidx.compose.ui:ui-viewbinding dependency needed.

Comment: What if there are constructor parameters for the fragment? How can I pass it from compose?

Answer (score 1):

I faced this exception too. I modified the sagix's answer to more convenient way for me. Check it out below. Don't forget use a childFragmentManager

```
@Composable
fun ReusableFragmentComponent(
    screen: SupportAppScreen,
    fragmentManager: FragmentManager,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    val containerId by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(View.generateViewId()) }

    AndroidView(
        modifier = modifier,
        factory = { context ->
            FragmentContainerView(ContextThemeWrapper(context, context.currentStyle())).apply {
                id = containerId
            }
        },
        update = {
            val fragmentAlreadyAdded = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(screen.screenKey) != null

            if (!fragmentAlreadyAdded) {
                fragmentManager
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(containerId, screen.getFragment(), screen.screenKey)
                    .commit()
            }
        })

    DisposableEffect(LocalLifecycleOwner.current) {
        onDispose {
            fragmentManager.findFragmentById(containerId)?.let { fragment ->
                fragmentManager
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .remove(fragment)
                    .commitAllowingStateLoss()
            }
        }
    }
}
```